# Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only

Tags: ios, swift, expression

I'm using [Expression](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Expression/) to create a very advanced calculator that takes string input from a user. I'm trying to add functions to give the calculator more features however I am not able to add custom or cast functions. Could you kindly explain me why the I am getting the following error.

**Code that works**

```
 public static let mathSymbols: [Symbol: SymbolEvaluator] = {
        var symbols: [Symbol: SymbolEvaluator] = [:]
        symbols[.function("atan", arity: 1)] = { atan($0[0]) }
        symbols[.function("abs", arity: 1)] = { abs($0[0]) }
        symbols[.function("log", arity: 1)] = { log2($0[0]) }
        return symbols
 }()
```

**Input that doesnt work**

```
        symbols[.function("number", arity: 1)] = { Float($0[0]) }
        symbols[.function("number", arity: 1)] = { someFunction($0[0]) }
```

**Error**

> Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only

Comment: Could it be that the closure must return a `Double` (and the error message is just misleading)?

Comment: OMG thank you sir! What a weird error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. [Expression.swift](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Expression/blob/master/Sources/Expression.swift#L44)  defines

```
public typealias SymbolEvaluator = (_ args: [Double]) throws -> Double
```

which means that the closure must return a `Double`:

```
symbols[.function("number", arity: 1)] = { Double($0[0]) }
```

Comment: The code now runs but it seems to be giving the wrong value for some reason when casting from a string. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @AntersBear: No. – I would suggest (if *debugging* the problem is not successful) to post a separate question with all necessary information.

Comment: Any idea how it might be possible for it to call a function I wrote with the value as input like `{ someFunc($0[0]) }`

Comment: @AntersBear: If `someFunction` is a `(Double)->Double` function then I would expect it to work.